# how to split content of data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, apply, lapply

I have data frame like this

`vf<-data.frame(A=c("v1v2"),B=c("v2v3"))`

is it possible to split the content as v1 and  v2  ..etc ..into two columns.

I used 
`ddply`
,but how different number separated?

expected out put

[image]

Also I stored my row name as variable

na<-rownames(vf)

It stored as "1", so I can't use it as vf[na]..

How can I store my row name in a variable and use it in function `rownames()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 vf$A.1 <- substr(vf[,1], 1,2)
 vf$A.2 <- substr(vf[,1], 3,4)


#> vf
#     A    B A.1 A.2
#1 v1v2 v2v3  v1  v2
```

Comment: thanks
na<-rownames(vf)

it stored as "1",,so i cant use it as vf[na]..

my question is..how can i store my row name in a variable and used it in funtion rownames() ?

Comment: is it possible to give any specific notaion insted of giving number ??

if idont know my content;is there any way to sperate data?

Comment: edit your question and provide a better example dataset that properly demonstrates your issue.